# C programming, variable changing value when it shouldn't

Tags: c

I'm using Code-blocks and I found one of the variables is changing to a different variable's value, when I don't expect it to. If I declare `goal` on a different line it fixes the issue. But would like to understand how these addresses overlap.
Is this a common bug in C language? Or problem with my device?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, goal, num[2], sum;
    printf("Input n: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &goal, &num[0], &num[1], &num[2]); //obtain integers
        if (num[0] != num[1] && num[1] != num[2] && num[2] != num[0]) { //check if all are unique.
            sum = num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
            if (goal == sum)
                printf("Proper triplet");
            else
                printf("Not a good triplet");
        } else
            printf("Not a good triplet");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I then `printf` at every opportunity and `goal` takes on `num[2]` value. Declaring `goal` with another `int` fixes it. Bring goal behind `num[2]` also fixes it. Is there some obvious reason that I should know causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, goal, sum, num[2];

    printf("Input n: "); scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &goal, &num[0], &num[1], &num[2]); //obtain integers
        printf("%d %d %d", num[0], num[1], num[2]); printf("\n\n");

        printf("%d", goal); printf("\n\n");

        if (num[0] != num[1] && num[1] != num[2] && num[2] != num[0]) { //check if all are unique.
            sum = num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
            if (goal == sum)
                printf("Proper triplet");
            else
                printf("Not b good triplet %d %d", goal, sum);
        } else
            printf("Not a good triplet");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int num[2]` allocates an array of size 2, but you are using it like it has a size of 3.

Comment: Enable higher warning level. GCC produces a warning about `&num[2]`

Answer (score 3):

The code has undefined behavior because there is no entry `num[2]` in the array `num` defined as `int num[2]`.  An array with a length of `2` only has 2 entries: `num[0]` and `num[1]`.

When you write to `num[2]`, you write beyond the end of the array and it happens that `goal` is at the memory location just after the end of the `num` array. This explains the *aliasing* side effect you observe.  Yet the behavior is undefined so anything else can happen and if you just move the definition of `goal` in the source code, the behavior does change.  All this is circumstantial and unpredictable, and not necessarily reproducible.

Define `num` with a length of `3` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> it will not work even though logic is correct

The logic is not correct; it has undefined behavior. 2 is not a valid index for `num`, so you are indexing outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue is that declaring an array in C declares the size, not the max index.

`int num[2];`

declares an array of size 2, which only allows access via `num[0]` and `num[1]`, `num[2]` is "undefined", and is writing to memory outside of the num declared space.

this error should go away if you using `int num[3]`, which has 3 entries, so you can use `num[2]`.